# Everything slows down except internet browser

Tags: windows, windows-vista, lag

I've been getting this crap several times a day and the only solution is restarting - which we all know is a pain in the *** and incredibly slow. I'm tired of dealing with it, so I'm asking here if any of you have encountered this problem and have a solution for it. Basically my whole computer lags up, everything takes up to 10 seconds to respond once I do something. Typing in Notepad is like a DDOS attack. However, oddly enough, my internet browser ALWAYS works regularly regardless. Notepad++ used to, but it just got the epic lag too. Don't tell me "well if all you do is browse the internet then don't worry about it", because I'm a developer (Notepad++) and I need that program to work so I can do my work.

Comment: Time to move to Windows 7, Vista was the beta release of W7.

Comment: Agreed.  Vista was a beta release of W7.  But W7 isn't much better either. 95 was a beta for 98.  2000 was a beta for XP.  But they haven't gotten Vista fixed yet, not even in W7.

Answer (score 1):

You may have SpyWare in your computer.  If you do, I strongly recommend you get these two programs to help remove them from your computer:

Malware Bytes
  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

SpyBot - Search & Destroy
  http://security.kolla.de/

You may have a virus in your computer, in which case using a reputable Anti-Virus solution would be a good idea.  There are many to choose from, and I particularly like this one because it has a very low memory footprint and doesn't drain resources with silly things like a fancy user interface or waste my time with ridiculous pop-ups that aren't related to virus protection:

F-Prot Anti-Virus
  http://www.f-prot.com/

Another common cause of those symptoms is that your computer doesn't have enough RAM and/or your hard drive is fragmented and needs to defragmented (the one that comes included with Windows is more than adequate for most people).

Over the years I've had experiences with a few failing hard drives that gradually slowed down for a few months before they stopped working.  I strongly recommend that you get full backups of your data before you do anything else with your computer.

Comment: I endorse this answer with a big thumbs up.  However, I use Avast! Anti-Virus.  I've also used F-Prot.  Both have a small footprint, and are transparent to the user.